# picasso: how to cancel all image requests made in an adapter

Tags: android, picasso

as usual we use an adapter to populate a listView. in the adapter we use picasso to load the images. i see that as rows are recycled when loading an image into an target (imageView) picasso will automatically cancel requests for that target.

how does one cancel all of the outstanding requests when leaving the fragment or activity?

Answer (score 30):

This answer may come a bit late, but maybe someone still needs it...

Define a `ViewHolder` which provides a cleanup method:

```
static class ImageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final ImageView image;

    public ImageHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        Picasso.with(image.getContext())
            .cancelRequest(image);
        image.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
}
```

Implement `onViewRecycled()` in your adapter:

```
static class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageHolder> {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(final ImageHolder holder) {
        holder.cleanup();
    }
}
```

Cancel the Picasso requests when your Fragment's view is destroyed (or whenever you wish):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recycler;

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        recycler.setAdapter(null); // will trigger the recycling in the adapter
    }
}
```

`RecyclerView.setAdapter(null)` will detach all currently added `View`s and their associated `ViewHolder`s will be recycled.

Answer (score 1):

> But only if you are not in a list/grid adapter! Requesting an image
>   for the same imageview/target (e.g., in an adapter getView) will do
>   this automatically. You should only need to cancel (and you don't
>   actually need to) if you're making requests and then leaving the
>   screen.

https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/83

Comment: i don't think i stated the question clearly. i'm *not* worried about cancelling requests for a row that is being recycled because of scrolling off the screen. i understand that picasso handles that. my question is how to cancel all the requests when leaving the fragment or activity that owns the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `RequestCreator#tag(Object)` on the requests made by your fragment/activity, then use `Picasso#cancelTag(Object)` to cancel all of them.