# ImageView lost their position after scrolling in RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, adapter, picasso

Position of the Images are getting disturbed after scrolling in the `RecyclerView` each time. I am using `Picasso` library to place the images in to the `RecyclerViewAdapter` . I have tested the recyclerView it is working fine, the problem is in the **onBindViewHolder** .

In this [VIDEO](https://i.imgur.com/wA7ENuA.mp4)  you can see that the first "hello" message disappear and the other image took that place.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
  val chat: Chat = mChatList[position]

  //image message
    if(chat.getMessage() == "IMAGE" && chat.getUrl() != ""){

        if(chat.getSender() == currentUserID){
            holder.textMessage?.visibility = GONE
            holder.imageMessageOut?.visibility = VISIBLE
            holder.cardViewOut?.visibility = VISIBLE
            Picasso.get().load(chat.getUrl()).into(holder.imageMessageOut)
        }
        else if (chat.getSender() != currentUserID){
            holder.textMessage?.visibility = GONE
            holder.imageMessageIn?.visibility = VISIBLE
            holder.cardViewIn?.visibility = VISIBLE
            Picasso.get().load(chat.getUrl()).into(holder.imageMessageIn)
        }
    }

 //text message
    else {
        holder.textMessage?.text = chat.getMessage()
    }
}
```

this code is for the layout of the outgoing messages. this is the side of the sender.

```
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_out"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#8DE3E3E3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/outgoing_image_message_iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_message_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded_rectangle"/>
```

And this bug message comes continuously In the logcat.

```
E/UIFirst: failed to open /proc/31416/stuck_info, No such file or directory
```

Comment: post whole `onBindViewHolder` method, code, NOT image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is occurring because you are not canceling the `Picasso`'s request so whenever you scroll the `RecyclerView` the images start loading and they get confused by the requests for images and started appearing in the `ImageView` so you just have to cancel the requests in the else block of the condition like this

```
Picasso.get().cancelRequest(imageMessageOut)
```

Now you will see that the `ImageView` is empty but  because you are setting your `ImageView`'s and `CardView`'s visibility as VISIBLE in the condition of *image message* so you will see a blank `CardView` in the place of messages. So for that you have to hide the `ImageView` and `CardView` or just only `CardView` because it is the parent layout for `ImageView`, so just set their visibility as GONE in the else block of image message like this

```
cardViewOut?.visibility = GONE
```

And don't forget to set the visibility of `textMessage` as VISIBLE because it has set as GONE in the if block

```
textMessage?.visibility = VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all: your previous question was closed, because "This question needs debugging details". So you have exchanged code to images, posted exacly same content, still without debugging data... why do you think that this question doesn't deserve to be closed also?

your problem is in `Picasso` image loading - you are starting it, but never canceling when your `ViewHolder` gets recycled BEFORE image is loaded. read how recycling pattern works (re-using previously inflated `View`/layout/row) and implement canceling `Picasso` requests like in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897441/picasso-how-to-cancel-all-image-requests-made-in-an-adapter)

if you switch order in your XML - `CardView` with image at first, second `TextView` - then you will get both "hello" text on top and loaded image under it. because this `View` was previously inflated as image, `Picasso` started loading image (network/cache, it takes some time) and post it to `ImageView` (with automatic `visibility` change), which at moment of setting image belong to another message at another position - `View` recycled and reused at another position

Comment: Thanks for advice, but can you please tell me what changes should i do in the code.

Comment: I tried everything from your answer but now it is more horrible than before it was. i also use teamViewer if you wanna see the whole code.

Comment: this question is already closed so you should create new one ([read guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) with updated code and behavior

Comment: I can, but there is no guarantee that I will help you, and anyone else can't post answer in here, as this question is closed

Comment: I have mentioned everything now what the question want from me. Tell me what should i have to mention there.

Comment: at first shrink bug/behavior description to one paragraph, attach link to video, then on the end put whole adapters code and whole XML of your row. you may also leave a link to new question in here (comment), so I will get a notification and maybe can help in this new topic, or also put updated code in this question but as above: only me and Anjana can answer you and there is no guarantee that we will know how to help you (I think I can, but without code it just a guess)

Comment: You can help me now.

Comment: how? this question is now opened, but still you didn't post updated code and "new" wrong behavior...

Comment: Updated code?? I update my xml code but not kt code because your suggestions make it worse than it was so you can post your answer with the right solution of code and i will try that , the code i posted is making problem so tell me the solution , if i found the solution i had answer myself not I'll update my question.

Comment: 1. You've posted updated XML, in which one and only change is reversing order. This gives nothing, won't fix your bug at all, just change a bit how it looks and should help in understanding what is happening and what is causing problem - I've wrote about this in answer, last paragraph. 2. My suggestions would fix your issue, you just don't know how to implement them properly, just like your current implementation is a bit wrong. 3. Sadly I've lost interest in helping you, you aren't cooperating... You don't like my answer? Downvote and wait for next one. Good luck!